# What is the quickest way to determine if a file contains a specific string?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to Perl and is working on a problem to replace a string in some files to another one, the only way I know is like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
$file = "default.properties";  
open (IN, $file) || die "Cannot open file ".$file." for read";       
@lines=<IN>;    
close IN;  

open (OUT, ">", $file) || die "Cannot open file ".$file." for write";  
foreach $line (@lines)  
{    
   $line =~ s/hello/hello hello hello/ig;    
   print OUT $line;    
}    
close OUT;
```

this treats each file equally and scan the lines of each file one by one, it would waste a lot of time if the contain does not contain the string I want to replace. I'm wondering if there's a way (like hash) to determine if a file contains a specific string?

P.S. Is there a quicker way for string replacement in a file instead of scan lines of it sequentially to find the line matches and then replace?

Comment: if your working with unix/Linux environment then u can go with grep then sed command know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no magic way to know if a file contains a string in advance.

I'd advise doing line by line processing instead of slurping the entire file.

You can do this using perl's [`$INPLACE_EDIT`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to edit a file as demonstrated below, or check out one of the many other methods listed in [perlfaq5 - How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "default.properties";  

local @ARGV = $file;
local $^I = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    s/hello/hello hello hello/ig;
    print; 
}
unlink "$file$^I"; # Delete backup
```

Or the equivalent in a one-liner

```
perl -i -pe 's/hello/hello hello hello/ig;' default.properties.
```

Comment: Getting the program to delete the backup kinda spoils the point doesn't it?

Comment: Just aiming to reproduce the OP's intent.  Windows requires a backup extension, so I always include one when demonstrating in-place edit.  However, on unix he could just use `local $^I = ''` and drop the `unlink` entirely.  I agree that keeping backups during development is definitely a good idea though, and will often demonstrate with the `unlink` line intentinally commented out.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm new to Perl

This has nothing to do with your immediate question, but you should get a good book on [*Modern* Perl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0985451947).

Perl has greatly changed over the years, and the way you write in Perl has changed. Since you're just starting out, might as well do it right. Looking at your code, it looks like you're picking up the coding style from the older releases of Perl.

Now to your question:

> this treats each file equally and scan the lines of each file one by one, it would waste a lot of time if the contain does not contain the string I want to replace. I'm wondering if there's a way (like hash) to determine if a file contains a specific string?

In the end, you have to read the entire file. There's no simple way around that. Yes, you could make your code *shorter*, but a read operation reads a file bit-by-bit and the substitute substitutes on the file bit-by-bit. Shorter code doesn't necessarily mean it's more efficient.

Here's your program written in a more modern style.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;          # Automatically kills your program on file errors
use feature qw(say);  # Automatically adds the \n on the end.

use File::Copy;       # Gives me the "move" command

my $file = "default.properties";
open my $in_fh, "<", $file;
open my $out_fh, ">", "$file.temp";   #Can't open a file for reading and writing at the same time!

while ( my $line = < $in_fh > ) {
    chomp $line;     # I always recommend that you chomp when you read.
    $line =~ s/hello/hello hello hello/;
    say {$out_fh} $line;
}
close $in_fh;
close $out_fh;
move "$file.temp", $file;
```

As you can see, this is still processing a line at a time.

Here are some of the items in the above:

- `use strict;` - Requires you to declare variables before using
- `use warnings;` - Prints out all sorts of warnings like undefined variables
- `use autodie;` - Automatically kills your program when a file operation fails. This can save you a lot of grief if you forget to check whether or not something worked.
- `use feature qw(say);` - Implements the "say" command. This is like `print`, but automatically adds in a New Line on the end.
- `use File::Copy;` - Gives you the `move` command. You can't easily read and write to the same file. Therefore, I had to use a different file name for input and output. Better would be [`File::Temp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) which allows you to define temporary files that are guaranteed to be unique.
- `open` - Use scalar variables for file handles. It makes it easier to pass a file handle to a function.
- `while` - A for loop has to read in the entire file before pressing. A `while` loop reads in a file line-by-line. Always use a `while` when reading in a file in a loop.

You can eliminate the loop, but it doesn't mean the code is that much more efficient:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;          # Automatically kills your program on file errors
use feature qw(say);

my $file = "default.properties";
open my $in_fh, "<", $file;
open my $out_fh, ">", "$file.temp";
my @lines = < $in_fh >;  #Read in all the lines at once
map { s/hello/hello hello hello/; } @lines;
say {$out_fh} join "", @lines;
close $in_fh;
close $out_fh;
move "$file.temp", $file;
```

This is using [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) which is a way of operating on an array without an explicit loop. It's a tricky command to understand, but it acts as a loop on the array you're passing to it. This is changing each entry in `@lines` with the substitute command enclosed in the curly braces. You'll see this a lot in Perl, and it can be cleaner in many cases than a `for` loop.

Finally, you could put the entire file into a single scalar variable (including new lines) and doing a substitution on that:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;          # Automatically kills your program on file errors
use feature qw(say);

my $file = "default.properties";
open my $in_fh, "<", $file;
open my $out_fh, ">", "$file.temp";
my @lines = < $in_fh >;  #Read in all the lines at once
$file = join "", @lines  # Converts file to one long scalar variable
$lines =~ s/hello/hello hello hello/g;
say {$out_fh} $lines;
close $in_fh;
close $out_fh;
move "$file.temp", $file;
```

Is this more efficient? I doubt it. Regular expressions are not very efficient statements, and doing a regular expression on a multi-lined, very long, scalar variable isn't going to be efficient.

True efficiency is a readable, maintainable program. You probably will spend a lot more time on maintenance than the length of time the program actually runs. This last example is harder to understand and probably more difficult to modify. Better sticking with either `map` or the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there's a way (like hash) to determine if a file contains a specific string?

Not really, no.

> Is there a quicker way for string replacement in a file instead of scan lines of it sequentially to find the line matches and then replace?

Also no.

That said, your perl script might not be as fast or optimized as some other options; for your case, most notably [`sed(1)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed):

```
sed -i -e 's/hello/hello hello hello/g' default.properties
```